# Java Sorting of Collection. Uppercase should come first and then lowercase

Tags: java, collections

I have list of String. The list is as follows

```
ABC,  DAY 1/2, DAY 1/1, DAY 1/16, DAY 1/2, day 1/1, day 1/52, day 1/32.
```

How can I sort this list of string using comparator and sort them in following manner

```
ABC, DAY 1/1, DAY 1/2, DAY 1/16, day 1/1, day 1/32, day 1/52
```

So, Uppercase words should come first and also sorting should happen by considering concatenated numbers in descending order 1/1,1/2,1/16 etc.

I have tried following code. I sorted it first using collection's default sort method. Its sorting them with uppercase coming first and lowercase coming later then I tried custom code but not able to sort in descending order.

```
 Collections.sort(list);
 Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String> (){
            public int compare(String s1, String s2){
                if(s1.toUpperCase().contains("DAY") &&     s2.toUpperCase().contains("DAY") 
                            && !s1.equalsIgnoreCase("DAY")  && !s2.equalsIgnoreCase("DAY")){

                    try{
                        Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(s1.split("\\/")[1]);
                        Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(s2.split("\\/")[1]);                           
                        System.out.println(" s1 " + s1 +" and s2 "+ s2 +" compare --> "+s1.compareTo(s2));

                        if(s1.compareTo(s2) > 0){
                            return 1;
                        }else if(s1.compareTo(s2) < 0){
                            if(i1 > i2){
                                return 1;
                            }else{
                                return 0;
                            }
                        }else{
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e){                            
                        return s1.compareTo(s2);
                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("In else--");
                    return 0;
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: I recommend you look up some examples (http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/comparator/java-comparator-example/, http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/, ...) and try it yourself. If you have a specific question about what's going wrong with your code then post it.

Comment: can I use collator here. But I am not much familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String data="ABC,  DAY 1/2, DAY 1/1, DAY 1/16, DAY 1/2, day 1/1, day 1/52, day 1/32";
        String [] list=data.split(",");
        List<String> llist=new ArrayList<>();
        for (String string : list) {
            llist.add(string);
        }
        Collections.sort(llist,new Comparator<String>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {

                if(o1.contains("DAY 1/") && o2.contains("DAY 1/")){
                    String s1=o1.split("/")[1];
                    String s2=o2.split("/")[1];
                   return Integer.parseInt(s1)>Integer.parseInt(s2)?1:-1;
                }else{
                    return o1.trim().compareTo(o2.trim());
                }

            }


        });

        System.out.println(llist);
}
```

output:

```
[ABC,  DAY 1/1,  DAY 1/2,   DAY 1/2,  DAY 1/16,  XYZ,  day 1/1,  day 1/32,  day 1/52,  xyz]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Only the thing is I applied the same conditions in if to  lowercase words 'day' in else if. Because only one IF for uppercase was sorting only uppercase words.